# Transitivity of -> in Coq

Tags: coq, implication

I'm trying to prove the transitivity of `->` in Coq's propositions:

```
Theorem implies_trans : forall P Q R : Prop,
  (P -> Q) -> (Q -> R) -> (P -> R).
Proof.
```

I wanted to destruct all propositions and simply handle **all 8 possibilities** with reflexivity. Apparently it's not that simple.
Here's what I tried:

```
Theorem implies_trans : forall P Q R : Prop,
  (P -> Q) -> (Q -> R) -> (P -> R).
Proof.
  intros P Q R H1 H2.
  destruct P. (** Hmmm ... this doesn't work *)
Admitted.
```

And this is what I get:

```
1 subgoal
P, Q, R : Prop
H1 : P -> Q
H2 : Q -> R
______________________________________(1/1)
P -> R
```

followed by this error:

```
Error: Not an inductive product.
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coq's logic is not classical logic where propositions are true or false. Instead, it's based in type theory and has an intuitionistic flavor by default.<sup>1</sup> In type theory, you should think of `P -> Q` being a function from "things of type `P`" to "things of type `Q`".<sup>2</sup>

The usual way to prove a goal of type `P -> Q` is to use `intro` or `intros` to introduce a hypothesis of type `P`, then use that hypothesis to somehow produce an element of type `Q`.

For example, we can prove that `(P -> Q -> R) -> (Q -> P -> R)`. In the "implication is a function" interpretation, this could be read as saying that if we have a function that takes `P` and `Q` and produces `R`, then we can define a function that takes `Q` and `P` and produces `R`. This is the same function, but with the arguments swapped.

```
Definition ArgSwap_1 {P Q R: Prop}: (P -> Q -> R) -> (Q -> P -> R) :=
  fun f q p => f p q.
```

Using tactics, we can see the types of the individual elements.

```
Lemma ArgSwap_2 {P Q R: Prop}: (P -> Q -> R) -> (Q -> P -> R).
Proof.
  intro f.
  intros q p.
  exact (f p q).
Qed.
```

After the `intro`, we see that `f: P -> Q -> R`, so `f` is our function that takes `P`s and `Q`s and produces `R`s. After the `intros` (which introduces multiple terms), we see that `q: Q` and `p: P`. The last line (before the `Qed.`) simply applies the function `f` to `p` and `q` to get something in `R`.

For your problem, the `intros` introduces the propositions `P`, `Q` and `R`, as well as `H1: P -> Q` and `H2: Q -> R`. We can still introduce one more term of type `P` though, since the goal is `P -> R`. Can you see how to use `H1` and `H2` and an element of `P` to produce an element of `R`? Hint: you'll go through `Q`. Also, remember that `H1` and `H2` are functions.

---

<sup>1</sup> You could add the law of excluded middle as an axiom, which would allow the kind of case analysis you want, but I think it misses the point of Coq.

<sup>2</sup> If you're wondering, the elements of `Prop` are still types and have very similar behavior to elements of `Set` or `Type`. The only difference is that `Prop` is "impredicative", which allows propositions to quantify over all propositions. For example `forall P: Prop, P -> P` is an element of `Prop`, but `forall A: Type, A -> A` is an element of the next level up of `Type` (`Type` is actually an infinite hierarchy).